# Resolv.conf problem when remastering

Tags: networking, remastersys

I am actually remastering (X)ubuntu 14.04. A tutorial is saying that I have to copy */etc/resolv.conf* to *$REMASTERFOLDER/etc/*. 
Everything works fine, but when booting the ISO there is no internet connection, but I can ping the local router.

In my Xubuntu 14.04 resolve.conf is no longer stored under /etc but under /run/resolveconf/. Also in the target-live-system. There IS the resolv.conf under /run/resolve.conf but it does not work.

Are there any issues I should know or could you help me?

Thank you so much.